# Can I calculate Decryption Time & File Size increase as Encryption Strength increases?

Tags: math, encryption, statistics, cryptography, cryptojs

I encrypt a file, and the resulting (encrypted) file is of a certain `Size`.

I can increase the `Strength` of the encryption and the `Size` of the resulting file will also increase in that case.

The `Time` it takes to then decrypt the file also increases when the `Strength` of the encryption is increased.

I ran `8` tests in total increasing the `Strength` by `5` every time and here are the results:

| Strength | Time (to decrypt in secs) | Size of encrypted file (Mb) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0.013 | 0.000088 |
| 5 | 0.064 | 0.001024 |
| 10 | 0.139 | 0.005376 |
| 15 | 0.199 | 0.023744 |
| 20 | 0.305 | 0.101144 |
| 25 | 0.503 | 0.427328 |
| 30 | 1.086 | 1.80188 |
| 35 | 3.348 | 7.59422 |
| 40 | 14.191 | 32.003072 |

I'm trying to figure out a pattern here, i.e. the relation between the `Strength`, `Time` & `Size`.

My computer crashes for any `Strength > 40` so I was wondering if based on these stats alone there is a way to more or less predict the `Time` and `Size` for a `Strength = 1000` for example (or other).

Answer (score 1):

I think that question will find a better answer on [math stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/)

But to me, it looks like an exponential, plot it into a chart, to visualize it better

Comment: Thank you I've duplicated my post over there. You may close this if you think it doesn't belong here I understand. :-)